# How does the keyword delegate work compared to creating a delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm slowly getting my head around delegates, in that the signature of the delegate must match that of the method it is delegating too.

However, please review the following code.

```
public static void Save()
{
    ThreadStart threadStart = delegate
    {
        SaveToDatabase();
    };
    new Thread(threadStart).Start();
}

private static void SaveToDatabase() { }
```

I am now stumped at this point, because the delegate returns `void` (as that is what `SaveToDatabase()` is) but, it's clearly returning a `ThreadStart`... Or is it?

If I were to write my own delegate, I would have no idea how to achieve this because the delegate would have to be void to match the return type of `SaveToDatabase()`. But it can't be; it would be of type `ThreadStart`!

My question is, have I totally mis-understood or is this made possible by some .NET trickery? If I wanted to write this method but create my own delegate, how would I ?

Comment: why not `ThreadStart threadStart=new ThreadStart(SaveToDatabase);`

Comment: I don't think anything is being returned since there is no `return` keyword. I think that a new `thread` is being created that will execute the method pointed to by the delegate.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ - it will actually, long term, take a few parameters.

Comment: This is an *anonymous method*, it doesn't have much to do with delegates.  They are kinda old school, you'd use a lambda expression these days.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, ironically I can do this with Lamda's (I started learning with .net 3.5 / 4.0 but am on a project which is on 2.0)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am now stumped at this point, because the delegate returns void (as that is what SaveToDatabase() is) but, it's clearly returning a ThreadStart... Or is it?
>
> If I were to right my own delegate, I would have no idea how to achieve this because the delegate would have to be void to match the return type of SaveToDatabase(), but can't be because it would be of type ThreadStart!

[ThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx) is defined as a delegate.  In fact, it is defined as

```
public delegate void ThreadStart();
```

So your code is not returning a delegate or a `ThreadStart`.  It is simply defining a function that matches the `ThreadStart` delegate definition.  The `Thread` constructor expects a `ThreadStart` delegate, which you have defined as the variable `threadStart`, which points to the `SaveToDatabase` function.

I tend to think of delegates as the old C++ term "function pointers".  Delegates allow us to specify what kind of function (parameters and return type) should be passed as a parameter to another function.

> My question is, have I totally mis-understood or is this made possible by some .NET trickery? If I wanted to write this method but create my own delegate, how would I ?

I think you may have misunderstood. But to answer this question specifically, the method you would write would just need to match the definition specified by the delegate type, in this case ThreadStart.  That method definition must return `void` and accept no parameters.  Your `SaveToDatabase` method matches this delegate type and is therefore the proper delegate method to create.

Comment: It's just a method that returns void. The ThreadStart() constructor code is a means of constructing the delegate pointer code.  You could easily just pass the method name that matches the ThreadStart delegate type to the Thread constructor as well.

Answer (score 5):

The word "delegate" is a bit abused. It's easier with classes and objects. A "class" is like a blueprint for an object. An "object" is an actual instance in memory, which follows the blueprint of the class.

For delegates we use the same word, hence I suspect your confusion. Consider the following code:

```
class Main
{
    public delegate int DelegateType(string x);
    public int SomeFunction(string y) { return int.Parse(y)*2; }
    public void Main()
    {
        DelegateType delegateInstance = null;
        delegateInstance = SomeFunction;
        int z = delegateInstance("21");
        Console.WriteLine(z);
    }
}
```

This code outputs "42".

The `DelegateType` is the type of the delegate. Like a class is a blueprint for an object, the delegate is a blueprint for a **function**.

So later we create a variable named `delegateInstance` which is of the type `DelegateType`. To that variable, we can assign **ANY** function that takes a single string parameter and returns an integer. Note, that we assigned **the function itself**, not the results of that function. It's like the `delegateInstance` variable is now a synonym of that function. Indeed, as demonstrated a line later, we can now use `delegateInstance` to call that funcion! Just as if `delegateInstance` was a function itself. But, since it is variable, we can also do all the same things that we usually do with variables - like pass them as parameters to other functions, or even return from other functions (A function that returns a function! Wrap your head around that!)

OK, let's see the code that baffled you.

```
public static void Save()
{
    ThreadStart threadStart = delegate
    {
        SaveToDatabase();
    };
    new Thread(threadStart).Start();
}

private static void SaveToDatabase() { }
```

First thing to notice is that you used an `anonymous delegate`. Another misuse of the term. When compiled, it results in something like this:

```
public static void Save()
{
    ThreadStart threadStart;
    threadStart = __ASDASDASD6546549871;
    var tmp = new Thread(threadStart);
    tmp.Start();
}

private static void SaveToDatabase() { }

private void __ASDASDASD6546549871()
{
    SaveToDatabase();
}
```

Note that your anonymous function was actually transformed to a completely regular function with a random name, and then that function was assigned to the `threadStart` variable.

So now this is just like the example above. Just replace `DelegateType` with `ThreadStart`, `delegateInstance` with `threadStart` and `SomeFunction` with `__ASDASDASD6546549871`.

Does it make sense now?

Comment: This is really good - thank you so much for taking your time to explain this, it has helped so much. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you are going to run an administrated subProcess, the method that is going to be executed gets represented by `ThreadStart` or `ParameterizedThreadStart`, but `SaveToDatabase` is `void` and it will be executed with `void` signature, not with `ThreadStart` type.

Example from MSDN:

```
class Test
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        // To start a thread using a static thread procedure, use the
        // class name and method name when you create the ThreadStart
        // delegate. Beginning in version 2.0 of the .NET Framework,
        // it is not necessary to create a delegate explicityly. 
        // Specify the name of the method in the Thread constructor, 
        // and the compiler selects the correct delegate. For example:
        //
        // Thread newThread = new Thread(Work.DoWork);
        //
        ThreadStart threadDelegate = new ThreadStart(Work.DoWork);
        Thread newThread = new Thread(threadDelegate);
        newThread.Start();

        // To start a thread using an instance method for the thread 
        // procedure, use the instance variable and method name when 
        // you create the ThreadStart delegate. Beginning in version
        // 2.0 of the .NET Framework, the explicit delegate is not
        // required.
        //
        Work w = new Work();
        w.Data = 42;
        threadDelegate = new ThreadStart(w.DoMoreWork);
        newThread = new Thread(threadDelegate);
        newThread.Start();
    }
}

class Work 
{
    public static void DoWork() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static thread procedure."); 
    }
    public int Data;
    public void DoMoreWork() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance thread procedure. Data={0}", Data); 
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if I created my own delegate, it would still be of type void?

Comment: You can create your own function. SaveToDatabase, SaveToDatabase2, SaveAgainToDatabase, if those methods are void, you can pass them to the ThreadStart constructor

Comment: Check the code sample from msdn I posted. It has the DoWork In other class with void Signature

Comment: I have seen that example, but, the word 'delegate' is never used and as such, I can't visualise how the delegate is consumed.

Comment: Thread uses his ThreadStart delegate, because you have to pass this Delegate type in constructor. Its like a function that received  int parameters, you can't pass a string. If you want to learn how delegates work, I recommend you to create custom events with delegates

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN

> A delegate is a type that references a method. Once a delegate is assigned a method, it behaves exactly like that method. The delegate method can be used like any other method, with parameters and a return value, as in this example:

```
public delegate int PerformCalculation(int x, int y);
```

So return type of the delegate will match the return type of the method it is delegating.

> Any method that matches the delegate's signature, which consists of the return type and parameters, can be assigned to the delegate. This makes is possible to programmatically change method calls, and also plug new code into existing classes. As long as you know the delegate's signature, you can assign your own delegated method.